# Rails 4 gem - ActiveSupport - method already defined

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, runtime-error, activesupport

I'm trying to make this gem (https://github.com/gshaw/common_validators) Rails 4 compatible and I'm having a bit of a trouble.

Changing [gemspec line 22](https://github.com/gshaw/common_validators/blob/master/common_validators.gemspec#L22) to `spec.add_dependency "rails", ">= 3.2"` will generate an error that

`` app/validators/date_format_validator.rb:8:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveModel (NameError) ``

Looks like that I have to explicitly require `active_record`, so I've added `require 'active_record'` to `test_helper.rb`.

Now the error received is

`` /.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb:36:in `test': test_invalid_date is already defined in DateFormatValidatorTest (RuntimeError) ``

Looks like I'm missing something basic, but not sure what. I've tried various things to no avail.

Any thoughts are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make it [work](https://github.com/gshaw/common_validators/commit/9766c7741673bf40ef2af7d828077a13aff1cb07) was to generate a new rails plugin as described on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html and use the test framework from there.